# prevent Google google analytics "auto track"

Tags: google-analytics

i want to prevent Google google analytics autotrack and track only my manual calls with _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])

how can i do this?

Comment: GA doesn't "autotrack" anything...part of the on-page code *is* a call to `_trackPageview`. Perhaps you should clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a javascript event handler to the elements you use for your manual calls:

```
<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','some url'])">Manual</a>
```